# Xamarin Forms Remove space from Entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a register page, with labels that show an error like "Username already exists". But the space between the Label and the Entry is a little bit too much. Here is an image of how it is now:
[image]

Now all of that is in a Grid, but the `RowHeights` are set to `Auto`, so this is the smallest size that the entry could get. The label, however, must be far more to the top (closer to the Username Entry).

Here is my code:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="imgUsernameStatus" Margin="5"/>
    <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Username" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtUsername" TextColor="White" Unfocused="OnUsernameUnfocused" TextChanged="OnUsernameTextChanged" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Username already exists" TextColor="Red" FontSize="11" x:Name="txtUsernameError" IsVisible="False" />

    <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="imgEmailStatus" Margin="5"/>
    <Entry Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Email" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtEmail" TextColor="White" TextChanged="OnEmailTextChanged" />

</Grid>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You have 2 row definitions with `*` height, this means they will fill the remaining available space. Your grid does not have a specific height value, meaning the more space available, the larger the row. You should consider setting a maximum height value for the cell. Although you will need to be careful because this value will likely need to be different across iOS & Andorid.

Comment: This is a snippet of my code, because it is a little bit big. This grid is inside another grid, so it has a static height! Sorry....

Comment: Ah ok, have you made sure that the column & row spacing is set to 0? it defaults to something like 5 or 10

Comment: Which platform are you developing on? I find visual studio windows is a bit nicer for doing xaml work because the previewer is better, showing things like the layout lines etc. Always helps with twiddly stuff such as this!

Comment: RowSpacing to 0 did the trick. I am developing on Android and deploy it to my phone. (OnePlus 6T)

Comment: It might be a shout in the future to use some css to override all of the default styling in xamarin like row/column spacing. I find I seldom use the properties aside from setting it to 0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for RowSpacing is 6 unit

Set `RowSpacing="0"`

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
      RowSpacing="0">

    <!--Your Content-->

</Grid>
```